# will_paginate can't convert Fixnum into Hash error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Everything is pretty much simple:
But It makes me crazy (

Controller:

```
@p = Product.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

view:

```
<%= will_paginate @p %>
```

error:

```
Showing d:/Sites/stockox/app/views/catalog/index.html.erb where line #1 raised:
can't convert Fixnum into Hash
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <%= will_paginate @p %>
```

trace:

```
ctionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `merge!'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:107:in `url_for'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb:115:in `url'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:93:in `link'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:45:in `page_number'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:28:in `block in to_html'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:26:in `map'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:26:in `to_html'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:94:in `will_paginate'
will_paginate (3.0.4) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb:33:in `will_paginate'
app/views/catalog/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_catalog_index_html_erb__739715019_37374852'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
c:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
remotipart (1.0.5) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__717039044__process_action__667298987__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.7.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
remotipart (1.0.5) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__405498685__call__41785573__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could `@p` be overwritten accidentally? If not, debug with `<%= debug @p %>` to have a look at what `@p` contains?